# Is it possible to change the delegate on a method reference closure in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I've been experimenting with closures and the delegate scope. I've been sucessful in changing the delegate for "regular closures" but not when converting a method to a closure via the `.&` operator:

```
class Mother {
  def method2() { nonexisting } 
  Closure method3 = {-> nonexisting}
}

Mother julia = new Mother()

// works for regular closures
def c3 = julia.method3
c3.delegate = [nonexisting: 'nonexisting']
assert 'nonexisting' == c3.call() // 'nonexisting' comes from the delegate Map


// fails for method reference closure
def c2 = julia.&method2
c2.delegate == [nonexisting: 'nonexisting']
println "this = ${c2.thisObject}"
println "owner = ${c2.owner}"
println "delegate = ${c2.delegate}"
assert 'nonexisting' == c2.call() // raises MissingPropertyException
```

Am I doing it wrong or it's just not possible to make the method reference closure to lookup free variables in my an object of my choice?